# Is there any way that enforce to set CSRF token in login form in symfony

Tags: symfony, csrf-protection, csrf-token

Obviously, I would like to enforce to set CSRF token in login form. Suppose that I don't add CSRF token in the login form and I've submitted the form. At this point, my request is, the response must be returned as denied so that I didn't add CSRF token.

How can I do this, or Can I do this?

Comment: Do you have a LoginFormAuthenticator in your source code? You can check if the CSRF is valid in the authenticator class.

Comment: Actually, I wanted to ask whether there an anotation to check CSRF like "@Route". Already, there is a way to check CSRF in controller like AuthenticationUtils. But, I don't know it, because it is not practical. I want to add CSRF checker to more than one controller which manages post forms. I don't know, did you understand me?

Comment: I'm not aware of any annotation that can do what you ask. In your case I would use an authenticator to intercept your form submissions and validate your csrf tokens. Take a look at this doc https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup.html

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can. You need simply create and output CSRF token:

```
<input type="hidden" name="_csrf_token" value="{{ csrf_token('authenticate') }}">
```

Normally that's all you need because https://github.com/symfony/security/blob/master/Http/Firewall/SimpleFormAuthenticationListener.php#L59-L60 checks the token automatically. You need to put exactly `_csrf_token` as field name and `authenticate` as token name.

You cas presonalize it if you want in:

```
# app/config/security.yml
security:
    # ...

    firewalls:
        secured_area:
            # ...
            form_login:
                # ...
                csrf_parameter: YOUR_csrf_token
                csrf_token_id: YOUR_authenticate
```

Watch out! This form login listener is deprecated since 4.2. Here is the example with gurad https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/form_login_setup that is recommended to use.

Cheers !

Answer (score 0):

You can inject the **CsrfTokenManagerInterface** in your `Controller` and use it in your **login** method as in the following example:

> SecurityController.php

```
class SecurityController extends Controller
{

    /** @var CsrfTokenManagerInterface */
    private $tokenManager;

    public function __construct(CsrfTokenManagerInterface $tokenManager = null)
    {
        $this->tokenManager = $tokenManager;
    }

    /**
    * @Route("/login", name="login")
    *
    * @param Request $request
    */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        // Get the login error if exists
        $error = $this->get('security.authentication_utils')->getLastAuthenticationError();

        // Last username entered by user
        $lastUsername = $this->get('security.authentication_utils')->getLastUsername();

        $csrfToken = $this->tokenManager
            ? $this->tokenManager->getToken('authenticate')->getValue()
            : null;

        if (null === $csrfToken) {
            //your exception
        }

        return $this->renderLogin([
            'last_username' => $lastUsername,
            'error' => $error,
            'csrf_token' => $csrfToken
        ]);
    }
}
```